# Which version of SQL Server 2012 should I download?

Tags: sql-server

I have been having trouble setting up Microsoft SQL Server on my personal computer and I think it's because I've been downloading the wrong version. I am downloading from Microsoft DreamSpark and there are so many versions to choose from, I'm not sure which one to download.

I just want to download a version that has everything, the management studio, the ability to make an instance etc. Would "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express with Tools 64-bit (English) - DreamSpark" be sufficient?

Comment: You need to know which version of Windows you are running.  Click `Start` right-click `My Computer`, and then click `Properties`.  Look under `System` for the version of Windows.

Comment: I don't know which versions DreamSpark have, but from MSDN you probably want the Developer edition which has everything and is unlimited. Express is limited to 10G database size I think (and possibly some CPU limit / affinity too) but that's probably sufficient for most projects. Are you sure you don't want SQL Server 2014 though? You can get 2014 express from Microsoft for free without going through DreamSpark.

Comment: What I mean is that I don't know which download to pick... like there are so many different ones. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express with Advanced Services 64-bit (English) - DreamSpark ??? I just don't know which one to get. I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: I think my university uses 2012 so I just thought I would try to download that. @Rup, could you possibly provide me with a link to that?

Comment: Here's a features table - it's for 2014 but 2012 is probably the same. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc645993.aspx Advanced Services appears to mean Reporting Services and the Full-text search service. There's an express download link on this page: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx

Comment: @Rup Thanks for the links! So when it comes to selecting a version should I just choose "SQL Server 2014 Express 64 Bit" or do I need a different one?

Comment: Aaah, I need management studio with it so I think I need the one with tools.

Comment: I don't know sorry, I usually use the Developer edition. (Which is available on DreamSpark I think? https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=83) You probably want 'with Tools' at least, but if you go for 'advanced services' anyway then you'll likely have the option of installing the extra or not. Developer likewise will give you the choice of what to install - depending what you need probably just the DB engine and SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm going to download 'Express 2014 with Tools'.